# Grunt a TypeScript to JavaScript with uglify

Tags: node.js, typescript, gruntjs, uglifyjs

I have 4 TypeScript files under the **ts** directory. I can compile them all into one file (main.js) with a source map (main.js.map) using the `typescript:base` task.

However, trying to `uglify` those files is not working when compiling *more than one* TypeScript file. It's as if `uglify` is getting confused when the `sourceMapIn` was made with more than one file.

How would you compile a TypeScript project with more than one file, into one file with a sourcemap (Back to the original ts files)

Here's the grunt file:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        uglify: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    sourceMap: '../js/main.min.map',
                    sourceMapIn: 'main.js.map',
                    sourceMapRoot: '../ts/'
                },
                files: {
                    '../js/main.min.js': ['main.js']
                }
            }
        },
        typescript: {
            base: {
                 src: ['**/*.ts'],
                 dest: '../js/main.js',
                 options: {
                     module: 'amd',
                     sourcemap: true,
                     declaration: false
                 }
             }

        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-typescript');

    grunt.file.setBase('../ts');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['typescript:base', 'uglify:dist']);
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem with the following environment:

```
grunt: 0.4.1
grunt-contrib-uglify: 0.2.2
grunt-typescript: 0.2.4
nodejs: 0.10.15
```

I had to change `uglify.dist.options.sourceMapIn` to `'../js/main.js.map'` and `uglify.dist.files['../js/main.min.js']` to `['../js/main.js']`, i. e. make the paths relative to the gruntfile location. Afterwards, compilation worked flawlessly and both `../js/main.min.js` and `../js/main.min.map` looked correct.